# Solve $ \vec{x^{'}} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}$, $ \vec{x} (0) = \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

$$
\vec{x^{'}} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\vec{x},$$
$$
\vec{x} (0) = \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0\end{bmatrix}$$

The question is the encode the solution as a flow $\phi: $${\mathbb R} \times {\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2 $

My approach is 
when I first separate the matrix into two 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$
$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

For B I found that for even matrix such as $B^2, B^4...B^{2n}$ have entries $2^{2n}$ on top left and bottom right and for odd matrix such as $B^1, B^3...B^{2n-1}$ have entries $2^{2n-1}$ on top right and bottom left ...however...I do not know how to represent them...could someone please help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
$$\overrightarrow{x}(t) =e^{Mt}\overrightarrow{x}(0) $$ so that $$ \overrightarrow{x}'(t) =Me^{Mt}\overrightarrow{x}(0)$$ where $M\in M_2({\bf R})$

${\bf Solution}$ :
$$ M =\left( \begin{matrix}1&2\\2&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Diagonalize $M$ : Eigenvalues $3,\ -1$. Then $$ v=(1,1)^T,\ w=(1,-1)^T$$ so that $$ 
M =P\left( \begin{matrix}3&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right) P^{-1},\ P=[v\ w]$$

Hence $$ e^{tM} = P\left( \begin{matrix}e^{3t}&0\\0& e^{-t}\end{matrix}\right) P^{-1}$$

${\bf Reference}$ : 10.3 solution by diagonalization in Advanced Engineering Mathematics - 3rd - (Zill and Cullen)

Comment: $$\overrightarrow{x}(t) =e^{Mt}\overrightarrow{x} $$ This is what we should focus on right?

Comment: I eddited. As know $M=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&2\\2&1\end{matrix}\right)$ Can you calculate $e^M$ ?

Comment: See the trouble I am having is listed in my post...please refer to it

Comment: I cannot understand what your decomposition $M=A+B$ mean. (1) Why do you do this ? (2) And your approach related with $A$ and $B$ is related to finding solution of given problem ?

Comment: I am able to solve matrix A but I had some trouble for solving matrix B. Since matrices A and B commute, exp(A+B) = exp(A)*exp(B)

Comment: You know some fact. But here to calculate $e^M$ we must diagonalize $M$

Comment: The answer I found is $\phi_t (x,y) = (\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}+e^{-t})x_0 + \frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}-e^{-t})y_0,\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}-e^{-t})x_0+\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}+e^{-t})y_0  $...is it correct?

Comment: Correct ! Well done

Comment: the only concern I have is can position of y , I mean (...,this), depend both $x_o$ and $y_o$?

Comment: Note that $M$ is $symmetric$. So if we know the first row, we can determine $M$. In case of $e^{Mt}$, (i.e. it is symmetric. Do you know ?), if we know the first row, we know $e^{Mt}$. Hence your opinion is right (it depends on only $x_0$)

Comment: if my opinion is right, then my answer should be wrong right since my answer depends on both $x_o$ and $y_o$ on top and bottom rows

Comment: What is your question ? I cannot figure out exactly

Comment: $\phi_t(x,y) = (...., (2) )$. In (2), my answer depend on both $x_0$ and $y_0$, should not that only depend on $y_0$?

Comment: Yes, it depends on both $x_0$ and $y_0$ in this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12864/discussion-between-afsdf-dfsaf-and-hee-kwon-lee)

Comment: $\phi_t(x,y) = (e^{3t}x + e^{-t}y, e^{3t}y - e^{-t}y) $

is the answer equivalent to my previous answer? if so, could you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to decompose $A=P^T\Lambda P$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix and then let $y=Px$.

Comment: The answer I found is $\phi_t (x,y) = (\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}+e^{-t})x_0 + \frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}-e^{-t})y_0,\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}-e^{-t})x_0+\frac {1}{2}(e^{3t}+e^{-t})y_0  $...is it correct?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Exactly.

Comment: $\phi_t(x,y) = (e^{3t}x + e^{-t}y, e^{3t}y - e^{-t}y) $

is the answer equivalent to my previous answer? if so, could you explain why?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Nope. The answer considers initial condition that $(x(t),y(t))=(x(0),y(0))$ at $t=0$. So your answer only gives a general solution, instead of particular solution.